# How often do the public facing ip addresses of azure devops change?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-keyvault

I have an Azure keyvault that has been locked down, but I need to access it from Azure DevOps. I know the IP address, but when reading online, it appears this IP address (or range) changes often. Is there a published list/rotation? Due to requirements, I can't make the Keyvault publicly available, but I need to access it from the public Azure DevOps, so I am looking for a permanent solution if one is out there.

I can monitor the logs on the keyvault for errors and then pull the public IP address from there, but that is less than ideal. It opens the process up to fail when that IP changes.

To fill out this question, here is the KQL for the keyvault logs.

```
AzureDiagnostics
| where ResourceProvider =="MICROSOFT.KEYVAULT" 
| where ResultDescription contains "Client address is not authorized."
| project ResultDescription, CallerIPAddress
```

This will return two columns, ResultDescription and CallerIPAddress, containing all the required information. Additionally, since posting, I have found the following [article](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/blob/main/docs/organizations/security/allow-list-ip-url.md) that includes the public IP addresses for Azure DevOps. Additionally, see this [Github Issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/13822) that calls out the duplicate IP ranges in the North and South US regions.

Assuming that the IPs listed are, in fact, CIDR ranges, these can most likely be added to your keyvault using the CLI.

```
az keyvault network-rule add --name "my-key-vault" --resource-group 'my-resource-group' --ip-address @('20.37.194.0/24','20.42.226.0/24','191.235.226.0/24','52.228.82.0/24','20.195.68.0/24','20.41.194.0/24','20.204.197.192/26','20.37.158.0/23','52.150.138.0/24','40.80.187.0/24','40.119.10.0/24','20.42.5.0/24','20.41.6.0/23','40.82.252.0/24','20.42.134.0/23','20.125.155.0/24','40.74.28.0/23','20.166.41.0/24','51.104.26.0/24')
```

Comment: I will assume that I've answered my question after finding the IP list article. As those are CIDR ranges, I presume any IP rotation happens within the range.

Answer (score 1):

Rules between services may vary, and we will need someone from DevOps to help, but across Azure, you can use this link, which provides list of IPs across resources:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519

Important to note: "New ranges appearing in the file will not be used in Azure for at least one week. Please download the new json file every week and perform the necessary changes at your site to correctly identify services running in Azure."

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, you need to access the Azure Key Vault from Azure DevOps.

Usually we access Azure KeyVault in the following two situations:

**Situation 1:** We need to access the Azure Key Vault from Azure DevOps Site. For example: link the Azure Key Vault in Variable Group. Refer to this doc: [Link secrets from an Azure key vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-secret-variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbash#link-secrets-from-an-azure-key-vault)

In this case, we need to add the [Inbound connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/allow-list-ip-url?view=azure-devops&tabs=IP-V4#inbound-connections) to the Azure Key Vault firewall.

The IP range is related to the Organization Region of your organization.

You can check the Organization Region in **Organization Settings -> Overview -> Region**. Then you can find the related IP range.

[image]

For example:

```
Asia Pacific    Southeast Asia (Singapore)  20.195.68.0/24
```

**Note**: You only need to add the IP range related to the organization without adding the IP range of all regions.

The IP range will change weekly. I suggest that you can use the script to get the related IP range in the [weekly file](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519) and add ip to key vault firewall.

For example: you can use Azure PowerShell task to achieve it every week.

```
$source = "https://download.microsoft.com/download/7/1/D/71D86715-5596-4529-9B13-DA13A5DE5B63/ServiceTags_Public_20231120.json"
$destination = "$(build.sourcesdirectory)\ServiceTags_Public_20231120.json"
$client = new-object System.Net.WebClient 
$cookie = "oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie"
$client.Headers.Add([System.Net.HttpRequestHeader]::Cookie, $cookie) 
$client.downloadFile($source, $destination)

$filecontent = (Get-Content  $(build.sourcesdirectory)\ServiceTags_Public_20231120.json | ConvertFrom-Json).values | ? { $_.name -eq "AzureDevOps.WestEurope" } 

$IP= $filecontent.properties.addressPrefixes

Add-AzKeyVaultNetworkRule -VaultName "keyvaultname" -IpAddressRange "$IP"
```

**Situation 2:**  we need to access the Azure Key Vault in Azure Pipeline. The Microsoft-hosted agent IP will change between each pipeline run.

You can add the steps in the Pipeline to get the agent IP and add the IP to the  Azure Key Vault firewall.

```
steps:
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  displayName: 'Azure PowerShell script: InlineScript'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: kevin0225
    ScriptType: InlineScript
    Inline: |
     $IP= Invoke-RestMethod http://ipinfo.io/json | Select -exp ip
     
     $IP
     
     Add-AzKeyVaultNetworkRule -VaultName "keyvaultname" -IpAddressRange "$IP"
    preferredAzurePowerShellVersion: 3.1.0

- task: AzureKeyVault@1
  displayName: 'Azure Key Vault: kevin0225'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: kevin0225
    KeyVaultName: kevin0225

- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  displayName: 'Azure PowerShell script: InlineScript'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: kevin0225
    ScriptType: InlineScript
    Inline: |
     $IP= Invoke-RestMethod http://ipinfo.io/json | Select -exp ip
     
     $IP
     
     Remove-AzKeyVaultNetworkRule -VaultName "keyvaultname" -IpAddressRange "$IP"
    preferredAzurePowerShellVersion: 3.1.0
```

The Microsoft-Hosted Agent IPs will also change every week.

For more detailed info, you can refer to my ticket: [Download secrets from Azure keyvaults using private ip in release pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66360668/download-secrets-from-azure-keyvaults-using-private-ip-in-release-pipeline/66364702#66364702)

Comment: WAIT, your public facing IP range changes weekly?

Comment: The Azure DevOps public IP range changes weekly, is what I meant to ask

Comment: Azure DevOps uses the Azure global network, IP ranges vary over time. Microsoft publishes a [weekly JSON file](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519) listing IP ranges for Azure datacenters, broken out by region. This file is updated weekly with new planned IP ranges.

Comment: I suggest that you can check the json file every week to make sure that you are using the latest IP ranges.