# Running Playwright tests in Azure Devops Pipeline to QA environment with IP restrictions?

Tags: azure-devops, playwright

I have created some Playwright tests in our NextJS project to run E2E tests. I want these tests to run automatically as part of the Azure DevOps Pipeline.

We have a pipeline that triggers as soon as someone merge to main. The artifact is built using microsoft-hosted agents. The artifact is then released to `dev.customer.com`. This domain has IP restrictions.

Now, the agent does not have static IP. Azure just assigns it a random IP from a huge range. So it's impossible for us to whitelist it to access `dev.customer.com`.

How should Playwright be able to access the site with its headless browser? Am I missing something obvious? I guess the main problem is that we have access restrictions to our QA site, but this have to be a pretty common setup I guess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbrowser#self-hosted-agents) with a static IP instead the Microsoft-hosted agents.

If you can modify the whitelist of your `dev.customer.com` in your pipeline with some bash/powershell command, then you can use Microsoft-hosted agents with the following steps:

- obtain the IP of the current Microsoft-hosted agent.
- add the IP to the target's whitelist
- run your test.
- delete this IP from the whitelist.

You can refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53422395/how-to-get-the-ip-address-for-azure-devops-hosted-agents-to-add-to-the-white-lis) and the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66360668/download-secrets-from-azure-keyvaults-using-private-ip-in-release-pipeline/66364702#66364702).