Run Playwright via Azure with a static IP address
To get around throttles and cloudflare we are currently running our playwright tests from a static IP address and are hoping to migrate to running our tests through Azure but I can't find if it is possible to continue to run the tests from a static ip if we are connecting through Azure.
I have searched through their documentation and don't see anything related to this.

Check this and see if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77807549/running-playwright-tests-in-azure-devops-pipeline-to-qa-environment-with-ip-rest

Does this answer your question? Running Playwright tests in Azure Devops Pipeline to QA environment with IP restrictions?
